# HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available in Spring MVC Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I really don't know what is missing in my files. I am always getting a requested resource not available error on the JSP page. I am using Tomcat 7. Here I am pasting my code anyone please suggest to avoid the mistake

Spring MVC Applicaton Structure:

[image]

**MyController.java**

```
package org.springframework.samples.tilesapp;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage(Model model) {
        return "homePage";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/contactus" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String contactusPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("address", "Vietnam");
        model.addAttribute("phone", "123546879");
        model.addAttribute("email", "amdin@sample.com");
        return "contactusPage";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>tilesTestApp-SpringWebMaven</display-name>

<!-- - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context. 
    - Applied by ContextLoaderListener. -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!-- - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller 
    implementations). -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**mvc-config.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">     


<mvc:annotation-driven />   

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"   value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

**tiles.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC  
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"  
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">  
<tiles-definitions>  

<!-- Base Define -->
<definition name="base.definition" 
    template="/WEB-INF/layouts/classic.jsp">  
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />  
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/view/header.jsp" />  
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/view/menu.jsp" />  
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />  
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/view/footer.jsp" />  
</definition>  

<!-- Home Page -->
<definition name="homePage" extends="base.definition">  
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Home Page" />  
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/view/home.jsp" />  
</definition>  

<!-- ContactUs Page -->
<definition name="contactusPage" extends="base.definition">  
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Contact Us" />  
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/view/contactus.jsp" />  
</definition> 

</tiles-definitions>
```

Please any one help me to remove the error from this Spring MVC application. I referred so many pages but I can't the mistake.

Comment: There is no controller in your `mvc-config.xml` nor a component-scan. Hence no controller, no mapping, no page result a 404. Add a component-scan to have it pickup the controller.

Comment: so now i need to add component-scan name like this  right <context:component-scan  base-package="org.springframework.samples.tilesapp"/>

Comment: Sorry i have test with that changes, still its showing error like this

Comment: It may be a ViewResolver configuration problem. Do you have tried simply return  " home" instead of "homePage" at your homePage  controller?

Comment: i have tried as you suggested, but still facing same issue

Comment: You need to fix your package structure. Your controller is in the default package but you have declared a package. Put it in the correct directory and hence package structure.

Comment: i tried as you suggested, now i'm getting this error org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Now i got the output. I have changed mvc-config.xml into spring-mvc-servlet.xml, this change gives exact output for me. But finally i have one doubt, when i changed mvc-config.xml into spring-mvc-servlet.xml and updated in web.xml also,then what is use of mvc-config.xml

Comment: Anyway thank for all your suppport